# BOL (real Home) hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-code

`Home` key in Visual Studio Code will bring the cursor to the virtual start o the line, in other words the first non-space character. Is there (or can I define) a hot-key  to got to a real beginning of a line (character index zero)?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to move the cursor always to the first column. Pressing `Home` two times places the cursor at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you install an extension I wrote:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillStewart.extended-cursormove

Just add keybindings for <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> to your `keybindings.json` file; e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "key": "home",
    "command": "extension.extendedCursorMove.cursorHome",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+home",
    "command": "extension.extendedCursorMove.cursorHomeSelect",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```